# SQL WHERE clause doesn't work with arrays

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, retool

I currently using a tool named retool to query data from my bigquery instance. The problem is quite a few of the field names use arrays and I'm having bit of an issue filter field names with arrays in the `WHERE` clauses.

Here's the SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    principal.ip AS ip,
    target.resource.product_object_id AS instance_id,
    metadata.product_event_type,
    principal.resource.attribute.labels[0].value AS image_description,
    target.asset.attribute.cloud.vpc.id AS vpc,
    security_result[0].severity AS severity,
    security_result[0].description,
    principal.group.product_object_id AS account_id
FROM
    `bq.datalake.events`
WHERE
    metadata.product_name = "AWS GuardDuty"
    AND security_result[0].severity = "HIGH"
    AND UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(metadata.event_timestamp.seconds)) < UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP "{{endingdate.value}}") 
    AND UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(metadata.event_timestamp.seconds)) > UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP "{{startingdate.value}}");
```

Here's the error message:

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [16:7]

I'm trying to filter field names that contain arrays

Comment: How is `security_result` defined?  The implication is that `severity` is an integer.

Comment: If `security_result[0].severity` is an INT64 and you’re comparing it to a STRING (`“HIGH”`), this will cause the error. Check the data type of security_result[0].severity

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing,

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64,
> STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [16:7]

points to a type mismatch issue in your SQL query. This error typically occurs when you're trying to compare values of different data types using the `=` operator. In your case, it's likely that the comparison `security_result[0].severity = "HIGH"` is the source of the error, suggesting that security_result[0].severity is not returning a string as expected. You can use the [BigQuery web console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) to verify the data type of the `severity` field.